# Embedding text and images from a database in a HTML page

Tags: php, html, asp.net, css

I am developing a website that is currently based on HTML, CSS and Javascript. I want to be able to update the images, film titles, descriptions and links from a database that I hope to grow overtime.

Here is the page (work in progress):

http://www.londonosophy.com/film_music2.html

Ideally I want to embed images, film titles and descriptions on this page from a .csv or SQL database so that when I update the database these changes are reflected in the pre-made and designed grid that I have.

Is there a best way to do this, or coding methods/ languages that would be ideal for this? I have looked into PHP, and ASP.Net briefly but wanted to get a professional opinion on this first before learning new languages fully.

Any guidance, methods to get started or example codes would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jamie

Comment: I would suggest using node.js as a web server: http://expressjs.com/ -- It doesn't cost any money and you already know javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to look into [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). It offers a system called *[Code First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)*
which uses Scaffolding and basically creates your DB for you.
A great tutorial (which demonstrates creating a db, and editing it through your website) can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like PHP & MySQL would be an ideal solution you can develop without having to buy extra software. But at the end it all comes down to what you prefer. Both PHP and ASP are equally able to give you good results. A really god tutorial for getting started can be found [here](http://www.lynda.com/MySQL-tutorials/PHP-MySQL-Essential-Training/119003-2.html?srchtrk=index%3a1%0alinktypeid%3a2%0aq%3aphp%0apage%3a1%0as%3arelevance%0asa%3atrue%0aproducttypeid%3a2).

Answer (score 0):

The best advice is to try them out.  There are several different frameworks and languages that you could use.  Each of them have their own strengths and weaknesses.

Give them a go, see which ones you like, you may prefer one language to another.

Find out which one is the best fit for your project time/costs/goals.

This will really help you get an understanding of what is out there, you'll learn a lot in the process and hopefully have fun too!